# Automatically switching the margin

Tags: margins, double-sided

[image]

I created some new commands to type the question and answer in the margin under "You Try It":

```
\newcommand{\margins}[1]{ \marginnote{
\flushleft{\color{framerule}{Simplify: \;  #1}}}[-1cm] }

\newcommand{\margina}[1]{ \marginnote{
\flushleft{\color{framerule}{Answer:  \; #1}}}[-1cm] }
```

Is there better way to do it using your code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problem you are having implementing this. It will be much easier for us to help you effectively when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its `check odd page`, `toggle left and right` features; I also used the [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package to define a theorem style and an environment for the exercises; the `example` environment then allows you to typeset the exercises with the desired formatting:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{framerule}{RGB}{183,41,41}
\colorlet{tryit}{green!70!black}

\newcommand\RedBox{\textcolor{framerule}{$\square$}}
\newtcolorbox{eoexample}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  check odd page,
  toggle left and right,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=\topsep,
  bottom=\topsep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  overlay={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) -- 
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) -- 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south east) -- 
        ([xshift=3pt]box.east);
    \fi
  }
}

\newtheoremstyle{myexa}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount 1
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
  {}%Theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{myexa}
\newtheorem{exa}{Example}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}}
  {\end{exa}\end{eoexample}}  

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\clearpage
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

An image of the layout for odd pages:

[image]

An image of the layout for even pages:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. One problem came up that I didn't anticipate... if the example runs from one page to another, the code generates extra lines at the bottom of one page and top of another page. Is there away to fix it using the current code? Also, to type the question and answer in the margin under 'You Try It', I created some new commands:                       \newcommand{\margins}[1]{ \marginnote{
\flushleft{\color{framerule}{Simplify: \;  #1}}}[-1cm] }

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for margin

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newenvironment{lrmargin}{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\ifodd\value{page}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{-.2\textwidth}%
\else%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{-.2\textwidth}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
\fi%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
}%
\item[]}{\end{list}}
\begin{document}
test \hrulefill test\\
test \hrulefill test
\begin{lrmargin}
test \hrulefill test
\end{lrmargin}
test \hrulefill test
\newpage
test \hrulefill test\\
test \hrulefill test
\begin{lrmargin}
test \hrulefill test
\end{lrmargin}
test \hrulefill test
\end{document}
```